# Why does React Native WebView go to about:blank in release build?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, webview, react-native

I have a component like this:

```
class PayPalWebView extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    payKey: PropTypes.string,
    payPalLoginUrl: PropTypes.string,
    onNavigationStateChange: PropTypes.func,
  }

  getPayPalLoginURL = () => this.props.payPalLoginUrl + this.props.payKey

  render () {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ url: this.getPayPalLoginURL() }}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        onNavigationStateChange={this.props.onNavigationStateChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I use it to handle the login flow for PayPal payments inside my react native app.

The development version inside an emulator works and correctly opens the PayPal login page.
When I switch to release build configuration inside the emulator, it doesn't work any more and only opens about:blank.

The issue occurred both on Android and iOS. However it suddenly started working this morning on iOS without me changing anything.

I've confirmed the output of `getPayPalLoginURL` being correct and also set the `source` attribute of the `WebView` to a fixed value. Also tried different values such as `{ url: "https://example.com"}` to make sure it's not related to the PayPal URL, but again it fails only on the release build.

I have also found other SO questions, where people suggested to set a fixed width on the `WebView`, which also didn't work.

Any suggestions to fix or to debug are much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

`source={{ url: this.getPayPalLoginURL() }}`

with

`source={{ uri: this.getPayPalLoginURL() }}`

check [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/webview.html#webview)

Comment: Wow! This was it. I can't believe it. Didn't even think of double checking that, because it worked just fine in the emulator with dev settings. Thanks! (EDIT: I'll reward it tomorrow, as soon as the time limit is up)

Comment: This was only happening to me on Android, onNavigationStateChange was returning url "about:blank" - Thank you going to link this answer on a few other SO posts. 
expo-cli 4.4.4 ; "react-native-webview": "11.2.3"